# Getting an error while trying to build my react native android file

Tags: java, android, react-native

I tried to build the android directory in my react native project in Android Studio and this is the error I am getting:

> 1Gradle sync failed:
> /home/pranil/my-code/conquer_app/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:585
> _processBundleRequest = this._createRequestProcessor({                        ^SyntaxError: Unexpected token =    at Module._compile
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)    at
> Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)    at
> tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)    at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)    at
> Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)    at require
> (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)    at Object.
> (/home/pranil/my-code/conquer_app/node_modules/metro/src/shared/output/bundle.js:12:16)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)    at
> Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
> (8 s 471 ms)

This is the line of code which is causing that error:

```
 _processBundleRequest = this._createRequestProcessor({

 ...
 ...
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to this. The problem is very likely in your node version. After upgrading to v16 it worked just fine.

Comment: tried this and it works just fine!